# Reformatted my Windows 7 install but forgot to get rid of my wubi install before I did so

Tags: wubi

Now I have a wubi partition on my HDD that I can't remove via add/remove programs. Would simply running the latest wubi install remove my existing wubi partition?

Comment: I have a feeling that by "I have a wubi partition" the author means "I have an Ubuntu menu entry in GRUB boot menu which I can not remove since I re-formatted the Windows partition which used to host the Wubi install".

Answer (score 0):

If you have done installation using wubi, it should have some files on the hard disk and visible in windows. You can just delete those files.